# Sorting results in recursive query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, recursive-query, jsonb

I have a basic **CATEGORIES**-like table consisting of fields like the **primary_key**, a **parent_id**, **title** and a **sorting** integer.

I am able to retrieve the results using CTE and convert them to a json array but I want to fetch them, aside from the parent_id, based on the sorting value.

So far:

```
with recursive parents as
(
    select n.boat_type_id, n.title, '{}'::int[] as parents, 0 as level
    from boat_types n
    where n.parent_id is NULL
    union all
    select n.boat_type_id, n.title, parents || n.parent_id, level+1
    from parents p
        join boat_types n on n.parent_id = p.boat_type_id
    where not n.boat_type_id = any(parents)
),
children as
(
    select n.parent_id, json_agg(jsonb_build_object('title', n.title->>'en'))::jsonb as js
    from parents tree
        join boat_types n using(boat_type_id)
    where level > 0 and not boat_type_id = any(parents)
    group by n.parent_id
    union all
    select n.parent_id, jsonb_build_object('category', n.title->>'en') || jsonb_build_object('subcategories', js) as js
    from children tree
        join boat_types n on n.boat_type_id = tree.parent_id
)
select jsonb_agg(js) as categories
from children
where parent_id is null
```

The above provides me with the result-set and the structure I want, but how can I make them follow the sorting value for both the nodes and the leafs.

Sample response:

```
[
   {
      "sorting":0,
      "category":"Motor",
      "subcategories":[
         {
            "title":"Motor Yacht",
            "sorting":2
         },
         {
            "title":"Mega Yacht",
            "sorting":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "sorting":1,
      "category":"Sailing",
      "subcategories":[
         {
            "title":"Sailing Yacht",
            "sorting":2
         },
         {
            "title":"Cruiser Racer",
            "sorting":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "sorting":2,
      "category":"Catamaran",
      "subcategories":[
         {
            "title":"Catamaran",
            "sorting":2
         },
         {
            "title":"Trimaran",
            "sorting":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "sorting":3,
      "category":"Other",
      "subcategories":[
         {
            "title":"Other",
            "sorting":2
         },
         {
            "title":"Airboat",
            "sorting":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have tried aggregating the sorting values in ARRAY fields and sort by it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `order by` clause in the `json_agg()` aggregate:

```
...
children as
(
    select 
        n.parent_id, 
        json_agg(jsonb_build_object('title', n.title->>'en', 'sorting', n.sorting) order by n.sorting)::jsonb as js
    from parents tree
        join boat_types n using(boat_type_id)
    where level > 0 and not boat_type_id = any(parents)
    group by n.parent_id
    union all
    select 
        n.parent_id, 
        jsonb_build_object('category', n.title->>'en', 'sorting', n.sorting) || jsonb_build_object('subcategories', js) as js
    from children tree
        join boat_types n on n.boat_type_id = tree.parent_id
)
...
```